# Python Matching multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I need to match multiple criteria between two dataframes and then assign an ID.

This is complicated by the fact that one criteria needs to be 'like or similar' and not exact as it involves a time reference that is slightly different.

I need the timestamp match second +/- a 1/2 second. I then would like to add a column that print's the ID in a new column in DF2:

```
DF1
TimeStamp                     ID          Size
2018-07-12T03:34:54.228000Z   46236499    0.0013
2018-07-12T03:34:54.301000Z   46236500    0.01119422

DF2
TimeStamp                     Size         ID #new column
2018-07-12T03:34:54.292Z      0.00         blank #no match/no data
2018-07-12T03:34:54.300Z      0.01119422   46236500 #size and 
                                                    #timestamp match within tolerances
```

In the example above the script would look at the time stamp column and look for any timestamp in DF2 that had the following information "2018-07-12T03:34:54"  +/- a 1/2 second + had the exact same 'Size' element.

This needs to be done like this as there could be multiple 'Size' elements that are the same throughout the dataset.

It would then stamp the corresponding ID in the newly created 'ID' column within DF2 or if DF2 was copied to a new DF, I would just add the new 'ID' column within DF3.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which rows you need in the final dataframe you may choose different join operators. One solution uses the combined dataframes joined by the column *Size* and then filters the remaining columns based on the absoulte time difference between the merged datetime columns.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Size', right_on='Size', how='right')
df3['deltaTime'] = numpy.abs(df3['TimeStamp_x'] - df3['TimeStamp_y'])
df3 = df3[(df3['deltaTime'] < timedelta(milliseconds=500)) | pandas.isnull(df3['deltaTime'])]
```

Output:

```
TimeStamp_x     ID_x    Size    TimeStamp_y     ID_y    deltaTime
0   2018-07-12 03:34:54.301     46236500.0  0.011194    2018-07-12 03:34:54.300     46236500    00:00:00.001000
1   2018-07-12 03:34:54.301     46236500.0  0.011194    2018-07-12 03:34:54.800     46236501    00:00:00.499000
3   NaT     NaN     0.000000    2018-07-12 03:34:54.292     blank   NaT
```

If you don't want any none merged rows then just remove `| pandas.isnull(df3['deltaTime'])` and use an inner join.